# Website now needs Rails backend for information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, forms

I have a friend who has a website that was built using HTML/CSS/JavaScript….

He now needs to collect some information (name, company, email, phone, interest level etc) on visitors to gain interest on an upcoming product launch.

He originally wanted it to send him an email every time someone filled out the form but realized that he’d always have to look back at emails later when he’s ready to launch the product.

Now he wants to use a rails backend to save all this information to a database. I have been introduced to rails but need some guidance.

Comment: Let him/her know about MailChimp.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could look over at the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/).  But if capturing data is the primary goal, I might look in to something like [Google Forms](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/createforms.html)

Comment: The site has already been built out including the input fields for each question…What’s the easiest way to capture these and put them directly into the database?

Comment: Well, if you have already built the input fields they are probably not being backed by a model, correct?  Are you already using RoR?  You have a few options; you can build the rails app and use a generator to get started with the MVC, or you could just use rails and plug in something like [redis](http://redis.io/) to just shove the entire post in to.

Comment: Really depends on what you mean by "built out including the input fields".